# How to create keytab file via LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, keytab

We can create objects like Users and Groups via LDAP.

The question is how to create keytab file using LDAP?

I need somehow to run the following command and obtain the `ffs.keytab` file using LDAP.

> ktpass -princ HTTP/xyzid.xzu.io@DC.YOURADDOMAIN.LINK -mapuser
> ffs@DC.YOURADDOMAIN.LINK -crypto ALL -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -pass
> +rndPass -out c:\ffs.keytab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about [Kerberos.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/Kerberos.NET)? This library contains several features for integrate LDAP with dot net core applications, include create keytab files. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513637/is-there-any-way-to-get-all-users-from-active-directory-using-kerberos) have one thread commented by [Steve Syfuhs](https://github.com/dotnet/Kerberos.NET/commits?after=559bec87d6eb1fb8698418c3aacafbbc7c32bdec%2034&author=SteveSyfuhs), principal contributor of this library.

Comment: I need to create a keytab file remotely, how does kerberos.net help me?

Comment: I need to connect to the AD server from a remote computer, then create the keytab file, and then download it to the remote computer.

Comment: @realPro, to connect to the AD Server from remote computer is the easiest to do: if you haver credentials of AD user (with no privilegies) it's sufficient to connect and consume Active Directory. And at Kerberos.NET docs contains examples to connect with AD Server.

Comment: The documentation contains examples how to connect, but there are no examples how to create a keytab file.

Comment: @realPro, you need to create a KeyTab dynamicallly? [Here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Create-KeyTab/1.0.0/Content/Create-KeyTab.ps1) contains a PowerShell example to create a KeyTab file and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088218/NET-to-Hadoop-Connection-using-Kerberos-Ticket) contains an example to start PowerShell from C# application

Comment: Not sure the purpose of the PS script. I need to programmatically connect to a remote Active Directory server and create a keytab file. I don't know how to explain it more simple than this. I use the ktpass command to create the keytab file, so the question is how to run ktpass command programmatically over the internet.

Comment: Please, chek if this thread is useful: [How to remotely generate Windows AD Kerberos keytab from a Unix machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/598499/how-to-remotely-generate-windows-ad-kerberos-keytab-from-a-unix-machine)

Answer (score -1):

LDAP is a protocol to access the directory but it cannot be used to run some command on the server. So the answer for your question is `you cannot create keytab using LDAP`

For better understanding the use of Kerberos and LDAP, check the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46188971/3496666

You can create objects like users and groups using LDAP because it was the actual purpose for LDAP designed to access the directory and make the changes within the directory whereas keytab is mainly used for authentication and getting auth ticket without the need for password.

If you could explain the purpose for your requirement, some may have solution for you in different way but not using LDAP.